# Python Tkinter SQL Placing a Placeholder in the entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

My placeholder works now but the problem lies with calling it in the SQL statement.

Without the placeholder, my SQL is working fine because each of my entry boxes have (example: textvariable="user") but when I place it in the configuration of my entry box the placeholder will also disappear. How can I make my placeholder works and also the SQL statement?
Thank you

```
class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Entry):
def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="PLACEHOLDER", color='grey'):
    super().__init__(master)

    self.placeholder = placeholder
    self.placeholder_color = color
    self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

    self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.foc_in)
    self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.foc_out)

    self.put_placeholder()

def put_placeholder(self):
    self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
    self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

def foc_in(self, *args):
    if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
        self.delete('0', 'end')
        self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

def foc_out(self, *args):
    if not self.get():
        self.put_placeholder()


def login(self, Event=None):
    find_user = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ('username' :  u OR email_address = %s) and password = %s"
    cur.execute(find_user, [user.get(), user.get(), passwd.get()])
    results = cur.fetchall()
    if results:
        if results[0][10] == "Admin":
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Page", "The login is successful.")
            page1.user_input.delete(0, END)
            page1.pass_input.delete(0, END)

            root.withdraw()
            global adm
            global page2
            adm = Toplevel()
            page2 = Admin_Page(adm)
            # page2.time()
            adm.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exitt)
            adm.mainloop()

        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Oops!!", "You are not an admin.")

    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect username or password.")
        page1.pass_input.delete(0, END)

user_input = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, 'USERNAME OR EMAIL')
user_input.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.455, width=300, height=24)
user_input.configure(font=("Corbel", 15))
user_input.configure(relief="flat")
```

Comment: You can't use `textvariable="user"`. `textvariable` must be a tkinter variable like: `tkinter.IntVar`, `tkinter.DoubleVar`, `tkinter.StringVar` or `tkinter.BooleanVar`

Comment: @TheLizzard how can I fixed my code? I have also this code before the class

user = StringVar()

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear that your question is on the *placeholder* in the custom `EntryWithPlaceholder` widget or in the SQL statement.  BTW the part `WHERE ('username' : u OR ...` in the SQL statement may be invalid.